# AWS Transcribe Post call Analytics

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, speech-recognition, amazon-transcribe

I'm trying to start a AWS Transcribe Post Call Analytics job from a Lambda function. I need to apply few custom categories(content match, sentiment analysis) to the starting job. I have already categories. Not sure how to apply these categories while starting a new transcribe job from Lambda.

Please help!

Tried to start the job using below code. How to apply the existing categories here.

`transcribe.start_call_analytics_job( CallAnalyticsJobName = job_name, Media = { 'MediaFileUri': job_uri }, DataAccessRoleArn = data_access_role, OutputLocation = output_location, ChannelDefinitions = [ { 'ChannelId': 0,  'ParticipantRole': 'AGENT' }, { 'ChannelId': 1,  'ParticipantRole': 'CUSTOMER' } ] )`